# Computational physics using mathematica

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, computational-physics, integration, software

So I was confused about this question on how to exactly begin to answer it. I am a novice in mathematica and I am teaching myself thus I require help in this question. From what I think I should do, is integrate the equation given at the end of the Potential from 0 to r and then plot the result. If I am wrong please correct me, this is a question I want to master because it uses a similar process and perhaps syntax to other questions I want to solve myself. Please let me know if my post is readable or not so I can make the changes.[image]Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If you zoom in with your computer, you can still see the writing clearly!

Comment: For future reference, you really shouldn't post text as images. Could you please remove the images and transcribe the relevant parts of the text? Use MathJax for the formulas. (The diagrams, of course, can still be images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate the expression over the *area* you need to write the area of the surface element (the ring of charge that is a distance $r$ away). If we write the position of a point on that surface in spherical coordinates (rather than (x',y',z')) then a little element of surface becomes

$$dA = R \sin\theta d\theta R d\phi$$

which they stated explicitly in the question. You therefore have to rewrite the expression for the potential

$$V(r) = \int \frac{k\sigma dA}{\sqrt{R^2 + r^2 - 2rR\cos\theta}}$$

(where the integral is taken over the surface). It becomes

$$V(r) = \int \int \frac{k\sigma R^2 \sin\theta d\theta d\phi}{\sqrt{R^2 + r^2 - 2rR\cos\theta}}$$

a double integral. Integrate once over $\theta$ and once over $\phi$ just as the problem stated.

Comment: Thanks! So, If I understand correctly, I would need to integrate the function from 0 to θ and another from 0 to ϕ . This should then give me the potential as a function of r?

Comment: No - you are trying to get the result for the entire sphere, so you integrate $\phi$ from 0 to $2\pi$ and $\theta$ from 0 to $\pi$. Of course the integral over $phi$ is trivial - you can do that one in your head - , after which it becomes a single integral in $\theta$. Think you can take it from here?

Comment: Oh, of course! Yeah thanks a lot Floris! Much help. As for the second part  (part B) I would have to integrate each variable to 1?

Comment: Set each variable to one, then look at what happens. There will be a step function - for r<R your result should be zero. Just as there is no field inside a hollow conductor...

Comment: Awesome! The plot looks amazing, this is why I wanted to learn mathematica. Thank you FLoris much appreciated.